# Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'sendDeviceTokenToServer'

Tags: flutter, appdelegate

This is my first time working with XCode and I am confused. First build and archiving was successful, however needed to make a small change in the flutter code.

Now getting `no member` error in AppDelegate. Please, see the screenshot[image: Appdelegate_error] Building and Archiving fails.

I followed the apple's own instructions. How do I fix this? Help appreciated very much!